# Identifying percentage in Fact Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, fact-table

I am new in programming and could not find an answer.

I have following dimensions(tables) and fact table:

- Customer: **CustomerId**, **HomeRegion**
- Regions: **RegionId**, **RegionName**
- MyTime: **id**, **MyHour**
- Fact table: **CustomerId**, **RegionId**, **TimeId**, **FactId**

I must have report as: **HomeRegion**, **Hour**, **RegionName**, **UserPercentage**.

[image: EXAMPLE]

As shown in the example, only 3.67% people whose home region is **A** move to **B** at 9am and so on.

I should create simular one.

**The problem is obtainig UserPercentage.** Here is the code I did so far.

```
SELECT c.HomeRegion, mt.myhour as Time, r.RegionName as CurrentRegion,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
        /*number of users who move from their home 
        region to CurrentRegion at specific time*/
)/COUNT(c.CustomerId)*100 as UserPercentage
FROM dbo.FactTable ft 
inner join dbo.Customer c
    ON ft.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
inner join dbo.myTime mt
    ON ft.TimeId = mt.ID
inner join dbo.Regions r
    ON ft.RegionId = r.RegionId
WHERE mt.myhour = '09'
GROUP BY c.HomeRegion, mt.myhour, r.RegionName
ORDER BY c.HomeRegion, r.RegionName
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you getting an error, incorrect results, etc?

Comment: No idea what code to write in the comment area

Comment: Well, not a whole lot we can tell you without tons more information.  Basically, you're going to need to work out who to identify someone who has switched regions, and incorporate that into a case statement for your count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the analytical functions
* no need to select or groupby myHour constant
* assuming one Customer should be located in 1 region at once (if not - it would be much harder to select)

```
select HomeRegion, CurrentRegion, 
count(*) / count(*) over () as overall_share,
count(*) / count(*) over (partition by HomeRegion) as homeregion_share, 
    from
    (SELECT c.HomeRegion, r.RegionName as CurrentRegion, c.CustomerId as CUST
    FROM dbo.FactTable ft 
    inner join dbo.Customer c
        ON ft.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    inner join dbo.myTime mt
        ON ft.TimeId = mt.ID
    inner join dbo.Regions r
        ON ft.RegionId = r.RegionId
    WHERE mt.myhour = '09'
    GROUP BY c.HomeRegion, r.RegionName, c.CustomerId) uni_users
    GROUP by HomeRegion, CurrentRegion
```

Comment: I had this error: Column 'uni_users.CustomerId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Column 'uni_users.CUST' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Try last version. U dont need to count customers at all, count(*) is equal in this case

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your comment area.

```
SELECT (TMP1.Count*100)/COUNT(TMP2.CustomerId) AS 'Percentage' 
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' 
FROM dbo.FactTable ft 
inner join dbo.Customer c ON ft.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
inner join dbo.Regions r ON ft.RegionId = r.RegionId 
WHERE 
r.RegionName IN ('A','B','C','D','E') AND 
c.HomeRegion IN ('A','B','C','D','E') 
) AS 'TMP1', dbo.Customer AS 'TMP2'
```

Comment: which table should I use in stead of TABLE_NAME

Comment: Use the table which has the CURRENT REGION , HOME REGION. If these fields are from different tables, you can also use join here.

Comment: Yes they are in different tables as shown at the beginning, but it is not possible to connect only these tables, we need to connect them to the fact table first. However the result is zeros (0).

Comment: (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.FactTable ft 
inner join dbo.Customer c
 ON ft.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
inner join dbo.Regions r
 ON ft.RegionId = r.RegionId
WHERE 
r.RegionName IN ('A''B''C''D''E') AND 
c.HomeRegion IN ('A''B''C''D''E')
)/COUNT(c.CustomerId)*100 as UserPercentage

Comment: Yes. execute this query & see if it gives proper results or not.

Comment: Execute the updated query, replace column name or table name if any. This should definitely produce results otherwise you are making a mistake in your select logic.